# SSRS - Need column that counts calculated columns with specific value

Tags: reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that shows the number of hours per week an employee has worked. Each week columns is a sum of hours each day in that week. If the sum of that weekly column is >= 20 then it's highlighted.  I also have a column totaling hours for the total date range.

I then have a column that needs to count the number of week columns that are over 20 hours or highlighted.  I can't seem to figure out how to do it.  I tried doing it through sql but my results are inconsistent (and wrong) because of trying to group on a datepart (I think).  The link is a current report sample

I'd like to figure out how to create the "Weeks over 20 Hrs" column.

Thanks in advance for any ideas.

[image: SSRS Report Sample]

Comment: [Edit] the question and show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Can you show us the formula you are currently using to get the 20+ hrs. count?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to take the definition of the week column and wrap a sum with a condition around it. Lets assume your `week column` calculates as the following:

```
'Week column
=Sum(Fields!SumOfHourPerDay.Value)
```

Now just add the follwing expression for `weeks over 20 hours`:

```
'Weeks over 20 hours column
=Sum(IIF(Sum(Fields!SumOfHourPerDay.Value) >= 20, 1, 0))
```

Comment: I think this would SUM all weeks on the inner SUM - giving a 1 for every row over 20 and 0 for the 5 rows under 20.